# Universal Selector * only work for p with classes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use that rule on my CSS, but universal selector only apply the padding for `<p class"name">`.

others childs without "classes" don't apply the padding.

```css
#GerenciarEpsOvas .item .infos>* {
  padding: 1px;
}

#GerenciarEpsOvas .item .infos .name {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="infos">
  <p class="nome">Anime:
    <font color="#bbb">Test</font>
  </p>
  <p>Ova:
    <font color="#bbb">Test 1</font>
  </p>
  <p>Episódio:
    <font color="#d47b33">Test 2</font>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<font>` element is deprecated. Use CSS's `color` property and a `<span>` instead.

Comment: `font` is an obsolete element and should no longer be used

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your css are looking for elements inside the class `.item`. Your HTML doesn't have that class. Second, if you want to style only the first element inside a class you need to use the pseudo-class "first-child".

```css
#GerenciarEpsOvas .infos > * {
    padding: 1px;
    color: red;
}

#GerenciarEpsOvas .infos > p:first-child {
    padding: 1px;
    color: blue;
}

#GerenciarEpsOvas .infos .name {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="GerenciarEpsOvas">
  <div class="infos">
      <p class="nome">Anime: <font color="#bbb">Test</font></p>
      <p>Ova: <font color="#bbb">Test 1</font></p>
      <p>Episódio: <font color="#d47b33">Test 2</font></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think his problem was not selecting only the first child but rather selecting all children, but his code only selected the first....

Comment: Hmm, perhaps, if so, only removing the missing "item" class from HTML, or add in his CSS could solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to select everything that is a child of GerenciarEpsOvas, .item or .infos. To achieve that (selecting multiple) separate them with commas.
I set the passing to 100px to make it more obvious:

```css
#GerenciarEpsOvas, .item, .infos > * {
  padding: 100px;
}

#GerenciarEpsOvas, .item, .infos, .name {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="infos">
  <p class="nome">Anime:
    <font color="#bbb">Test</font>
  </p>
  <p>Ova:
    <font color="#bbb">Test 1</font>
  </p>
  <p>Episódio:
    <font color="#d47b33">Test 2</font>
  </p>
</div>
```

In your example your selecting decendants. [Read here](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)